# How to find emirp numbers using NumPy?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I want to find prime numbers whose digits reversed is also a prime number, including palindromic primes, and I also wish to find primes with such property in other bases, not just decimal. Prime numbers whose reversal of digits are also prime numbers are called emirp and more information about it is on this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emirp).

I have already implemented a solution that gives the correct output, which is shown below. I would like to implement the same thing using NumPy.

```py
import numpy as np
from itertools import cycle

def prime_wheel_sieve(n: int) -> np.ndarray:
    wheel = cycle([4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 6])
    primes = np.ones(n + 1, dtype=bool)
    primes[:2] = False
    for square, step in ((4, 2), (9, 6), (25, 10)):
        primes[square::step] = False

    k = 7
    while (square := k * k) <= n:
        if primes[k]:
            primes[square :: 2 * k] = False

        k += next(wheel)
    return np.where(primes)[0]


DIGITS = {
    **{n: chr(n + 48) for n in range(10)},
    **{n: chr(n + 87) for n in range(10, 36)}
}

def to_base_str(n: int, base: int) -> str:
    if not 2 <= base <= 36:
        raise ValueError

    s = []
    while n:
        n, d = divmod(n, base)
        s.append(DIGITS[d])

    return "".join(s[::-1])


def to_base(n: int, base: int) -> str | tuple:
    if base < 2:
        raise ValueError

    if base <= 36:
        return to_base_str(n, base)

    s = []
    while n:
        n, d = divmod(n, base)
        s.append(d)

    return tuple(s[::-1])


def from_base(s: str | tuple, base: int) -> int:
    if base < 2:
        raise ValueError
    if base <= 36:
        return int(s, base)
    return sum(d * base ** i for i, d in enumerate(s[::-1]))


def emirp(n: int, base: int = 10) -> np.ndarray:
    primes = prime_wheel_sieve(n)
    primes = primes[primes > base]
    elist = [to_base(p, base) for p in primes]
    eset = set(elist)
    return primes[[i for i, e in enumerate(elist) if e[::-1] in eset]]
```

Examples:

```
In [90]: emirp(1000, 2)
Out[90]:
array([  3,   5,   7,  11,  13,  17,  23,  29,  31,  37,  41,  43,  47,
        53,  61,  67,  71,  73,  83,  97, 101, 107, 113, 127, 131, 151,
       163, 167, 173, 181, 193, 197, 199, 223, 227, 229, 233, 251, 257,
       263, 269, 277, 283, 307, 313, 331, 337, 349, 353, 359, 373, 383,
       409, 421, 431, 433, 443, 449, 461, 463, 479, 487, 491, 503, 509,
       521, 571, 577, 599, 601, 617, 619, 631, 643, 653, 661, 677, 683,
       691, 701, 709, 727, 739, 757, 773, 797, 821, 823, 827, 839, 853,
       857, 881, 883, 907, 911, 937, 941, 947, 953, 967])

In [91]: emirp(1000, 10)
Out[91]:
array([ 11,  13,  17,  31,  37,  71,  73,  79,  97, 101, 107, 113, 131,
       149, 151, 157, 167, 179, 181, 191, 199, 311, 313, 337, 347, 353,
       359, 373, 383, 389, 701, 709, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761,
       769, 787, 797, 907, 919, 929, 937, 941, 953, 967, 971, 983, 991])

In [92]: emirp(1000, 5)
Out[92]:
array([  7,  11,  13,  17,  19,  23,  29,  31,  37,  41,  47,  59,  61,
        67,  71,  73,  79,  83,  89,  97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127,
       131, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 191, 193, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233,
       239, 251, 257, 269, 271, 277, 281, 293, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349,
       353, 359, 367, 379, 397, 421, 431, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463,
       479, 491, 503, 521, 523, 547, 563, 571, 577, 599, 601, 613, 617,
       619, 631, 701, 751, 761, 881, 911])
```

---

### Update

I just found out `np.base_repr`, it almost does exactly the same thing as my custom function, except it doesn't handle bases larger than 36, as with `int`, and it doesn't take an array as input. So it is useless here. And I only found it because I Googled a topic completely irrelevant to it.

Comment: Your question contains a lot of information about prime numbers and a lot of code. Is the essence of your question how to reverse a single digit using numpy? Or how to find emirp numbers with numpy? Then try to keep it short and to the point, and not include unrelated information.

Comment: I searched `"emirp" "numpy"` (exact keyword) using Google, and the only relevant result is this very question at the top, other results are ostensibly relevant, they shown how to find emirp numbers in Python, but none contains a NumPy implementation, and all implementations are inferior to mine.

Comment: It is not clear why you want to use Numpy here. Especially since Numpy is not well suited for problems like finding prime numbers (due to their irregular structure). Do you try this to make this faster? But if so, isn't the question how to make it faster? There are other ways to make it faster. Is it a homework?

Comment: Maybe I should be more clear, but it isn't homework. It is simply self-imposed programming challenge. I am not in school of any kind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting numbers to strings to reverse their digits and then converting the reversed strings back to integers is not efficient.  Instead, you should do it all in integer space, like this:

```
def reverse_digits(value, base):
    result = 0
    while value > 0:
        right_digit = value % base
        value = value // base
        result = result * base + right_digit 
    return result
```

That's a lot less computation than using strings.

Applying the above function in a loop will be fairly slow.  An easy solution is Numba, a JIT compiler library.  To make it efficient to apply elementwise on entire arrays, use `numba.vectorize` to create a NumPy "ufunc":

```
import numba

@numba.vectorize(nopython=True)
def reverse_digits(value, base):
    # ...
```

And you'll have a compiled function which runs at native speed, as if you had written it in C.  So you can filter a whole NumPy array of `primes` like this:

```
primes[np.isin(reverse_digits(primes, 10), primes)]
```

For a simple example on my machine, Numba gives about a 200x speedup.

Finally, reversing digits is not necessary: you only need to check if `value == reverse_digits(value, base)`.  That might allow further speedups.

Comment: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment`. You haven't defined result, according to my test, you should add `result = 0`.

Comment: By the way, `primes[primes == reverse_digits(primes, 10)]` outputs palindromic primes in base-10. I have found that `primes[np.isin(reverse_digits(primes, 10), primes)]` does what I intended.

Comment: Note that Numba integer are bounded to 64-bit while the one of CPython are not. This means the code will be limited to compute only relatively short numbers. This should not be critical since `prime_wheel_sieve` is not able to compute large `n` but I think it is worth a comment. Besides note that the Numba division has the semantic of the CPython one by default so it is a bit slower than the native one but the code should be already quite fast compared to CPython. For computing codes like this using the PyPy interpreter first (without any code change) might be better suited.

Answer (score 0):

The remainder and floor division result can be obtained by a single function call: `divmod`, this will eliminate the computational redundancy of using `//` and `%`.

And `numba.vectorize` can be further tweaked with more flags to make it more efficient.

`primes[primes == reverse_digits(primes, 10)]` means to find primes whose digit reversal equals to themselves, in other words palindromic primes.

I intend to find primes whose digit reversal in a given base is also a prime number, so I had to filter the primes by membership checking, namely I need to find the digit reversals that are inside the primes array.

`primes[np.isin(reverse_digits(primes, base), primes)]` does what I intend.

But `np.isin` is surprisingly inefficient, a better method would be to convert the `primes` array to set while bypassing `numpy` with `arr.tolist()`, and then use list comprehension to build the mask.

```
import numba
import numpy as np
from itertools import cycle

def prime_wheel_sieve(n: int) -> np.ndarray:
    wheel = cycle([4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 6])
    primes = np.ones(n + 1, dtype=bool)
    primes[:2] = False
    for square, step in ((4, 2), (9, 6), (25, 10)):
        primes[square::step] = False

    k = 7
    while (square := k * k) <= n:
        if primes[k]:
            primes[square :: 2 * k] = False

        k += next(wheel)

    return np.where(primes)[0]

@numba.vectorize(nopython=True, cache=True, fastmath=True, forceobj=False)
def reverse_digits(value: int | np.ndarray, base: int) -> np.ndarray:
    result = 0
    while value:
        value, remainder = divmod(value, base)
        result = result * base + remainder
    return result

def emirp(n: int, base: int = 10) -> np.ndarray:
    primes = prime_wheel_sieve(n)
    flipped = reverse_digits(primes, base).tolist()
    prime_set = set(primes.tolist())
    return primes[[x in prime_set for x in flipped]]
```

And single digit primes are palindromic primes. So including them is correct and will eliminate unnecessary computations.

---

But actually `np.isin` scales better for larger inputs, I haven't considered that, it turns out for small inputs Python wins, because there is NumPy overhead, but for larger inputs Python loses, NumPy works better.

```
def emirp(n: int, base: int = 10) -> np.ndarray:
    primes = prime_wheel_sieve(n)
    flipped = reverse_digits(primes, base)
    return primes[np.isin(flipped, primes)]
```

Comment: I made the fixes you suggested on my answer (thanks), so you can probably delete this self-answer.