# How to reverse strings in a NumPy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to reverse the order of characters in each string element of a NumPy array. For example, given the following input:

```py
array(['2', '3', '5', '7', '11', '13', '17', '19', '23', '29', '31', '37',
       '41', '43', '47', '53', '59', '61', '67', '71', '73', '79', '83',
       '89', '97'], dtype='<U2')
```

I want to obtain the following output (***without using Python `for` loop***):

```py
array(['2', '3', '5', '7', '11', '31', '71', '91', '32', '92', '13', '73',
       '14', '34', '74', '35', '95', '16', '76', '17', '37', '97', '38',
       '98', '79'], dtype='<U2')
```

I know that I can use `arr[::-1]` to reverse the order of elements in a NumPy array, but that isn't the topic of this question, and  `np.array([e[::-1] for e in arr])` is inefficient and against the point of NumPy.

The array was created using a vectorized version of the base conversion function [`np.vectorize(to_base_str)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76495180/how-to-find-emirp-numbers-using-numpy).

How can I reverse the order of characters in each string element of a NumPy array using vectorization? I have searched online but have not found a solution. Note that `arr[..., ::-1]` does not work for string elements in a NumPy array.

(Code is mine, but I did use the "AI suggested edits" feature)

Comment: `f = lambda x: x[::-1]`, `reverseall = np.vectorize(f)`, `res=reverseall(array)`, something like this?

Comment: That is allowed, yes, but I am wondering if there is any built-in NumPy methods I can use to do this.

Comment: Why not instead reverse the **numbers** in the array of numbers that you used to produce this array of strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.array([e[::-1] for e in arr])` is the straight forward way of doing this, and is NOT bad `numpy`.  or bypass numpy entirely with `[e[::-1] for e in arr.tolist()]`.  You could also do something similar with `np.vectorize` or `np.frompyfunc`.  These might scale a bit better.

'vectorize' in `numpy` means using compiled methods (and operators) to do the necessary iterations in compiled code.  Those are nearly all numeric operations.  For strings, `numpy` uses Python string methods.  It does not have its own compiled string operations.  Even the `np.char` functions use python string methods.

So there's no `numpy` equivalent to `astr[::-1]`.

Some comparative times

```
In [16]: timeit np.array([s[::-1] for s in arr])
36.1 µs ± 151 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

In [17]: timeit np.array([s[::-1] for s in arr.tolist()])
21.1 µs ± 76.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

In [18]: timeit [s[::-1] for s in arr.tolist()]
8.29 µs ± 23.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [20]: timeit np.vectorize(lambda s: s[::-1])(arr)
65.9 µs ± 165 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

In [21]: timeit np.frompyfunc(lambda s: s[::-1],1,1)(arr)
20.3 µs ± 76.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following does the job by considering a different view of the original array. This means no additional arrays (and thus memory) are required. And no for loops :)

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array(['2', '3', '5', '7', '11', '13', '17', '19', '23', '29', '31', '37',
       '41', '43', '47', '53', '59', '61', '67', '71', '73', '79', '83',
       '89', '97'], dtype='<U2')

B = A.view(np.uint32)           # Interpret as individual numbers
B = B.reshape((A.shape[0],2))   # Group numbers in pairs
B[B[:,1] != 0, :] = B[B[:,1] != 0, ::-1] # Flip pairs if more than 1 digit

print(A) # ['2' '3' '5' '7' '11' '31' '71' '91' '32' '92' '13' '73' '14' '34' '74' '35' '95' '16' '76' '17' '37' '97' '38' '98' '79']
```

For short arrays, like the one you gave, @hpaulj's answer is faster. But for larger arrays, this method is faster. As an example, for an array of 100,000 elements, this method is approximately 5x faster compared to @hpaulj's fastest method (`[s[::-1] for s in arr.tolist()]`).

Comment: *"much faster"* - How much?

Comment: I think this works because the `U2` string format allocates a fixed 4 bytes to each unicode character, allowing you view each as 'uint32'.  It wouldn't work with python unicode strings.