# How to generate twin primes in NumPy?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I want to generate [twin primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime) using NumPy. Two prime numbers are twin primes if their difference is 2.

My idea is simple: generate the prime numbers using the Sieve of Eratosthenes, then filter out adjacent prime numbers that don't have a difference of 2.

Sieve of Erastothenes code implementation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76495180/how-to-find-emirp-numbers-using-numpy).

This is the implementation of the twin prime filter I have written:

```py
import numpy as np

def twin_primes(n: int) -> np.ndarray:
   primes = prime_wheel_sieve(n)
   mask = np.isin(primes + 2, primes)
   mask |= np.concatenate([[False], mask])[:-1]
   return primes[mask]
```

The expected output should be:

```py
In [367]: twin_primes(1000)
Out[367]:
array([  3,   5,   7,  11,  13,  17,  19,  29,  31,  41,  43,  59,  61,
        71,  73, 101, 103, 107, 109, 137, 139, 149, 151, 179, 181, 191,
       193, 197, 199, 227, 229, 239, 241, 269, 271, 281, 283, 311, 313,
       347, 349, 419, 421, 431, 433, 461, 463, 521, 523, 569, 571, 599,
       601, 617, 619, 641, 643, 659, 661, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829,
       857, 859, 881, 883], dtype=int64)
```

I first use membership checking to find prime numbers that, when incremented by 2, are also prime. This would find the first number in all twin prime pairs, but it will fail to find the second number of the pairs.

This problem boils down to flipping all `False` values in a NumPy array immediately after `True` values, since in all twin prime pairs the second number must be the next prime after the first.

I am unsure of how to flip every `False` after `True`, and Google is of no help. So I right-rotated the mask by one to get the second number in all pairs and combined the two masks using the bitwise OR operator.

Is there a simpler way to flip all `False` after `True`?

(as with my previous two questions, I used AI suggested edits)

Comment: Slightly different approach: how about just finding the first number in all twin prime pairs (which you already do), then adding 2 to get the second member of each pair?

Comment: But then I have to use `np.concatenate` and `np.unique`, because 5 appears twice. (3, 5) and (5, 7) are two pairs of twin primes that are adjacent, I want the numbers to be unique, and there might be other adjacent twin primes. I also want the numbers to be sorted.

Comment: Fair enough. Although note that there can be no other "overlapping pairs" of twin primes apart from (3, 5, 7). Apart from 2 and 3, every prime number is congruent (mod 6) to 1 or 5. So if N and N+2 are both prime, then `N%6 = 5`, `(N+2) % 6 = 1`, and therefore `(N + 4) % 6 = 3` and cannot be prime (it's an odd multiple of 3).

Comment: No there aren't any other adjacent twin primes. There can't be. A sequence of 3 successive odds (like 3,5,7 or 15,17,19) has to contain one factor of 3. So a non-prime. Except in the unique case when that factor 3 is 3 itself, a prime. Hence 3,5,7. But after that, that's it

Comment: (btw, I think your method of right-shifting the mask and ORing is fine!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your particular concern is the call to `np.isin`, you can take advantage of the fact we know 2 is not a twin prime and do the following:

```
def twin_primes_new(n: int) -> np.ndarray:
   primes = prime_wheel_sieve(n)
   mask = (primes-2)[1:] == primes[:-1]
   mask[:-1] |= mask[1:]
   return primes[1:][mask]

print(timeit.timeit('twin_primes_orig(1000)', globals=globals()))
print(timeit.timeit('twin_primes_new(1000)', globals=globals()))
```

I do see that giving a decent sized improvement to performance:

```
30.4948765
9.421712999999997
```

If it bothers you that we're assuming 2 isn't a twin prime, you can, at the cost of half a second on 1,000,000 executions, do:

```
   ...
   mask = np.zeros(primes.shape, dtype=bool)
   mask[1:] = (primes-2)[1:] == primes[:-1]
   mask[:-1] |= mask[1:]
   return primes[mask]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is fine. Another approach that is more intuitive is too simply take the difference of the boolean array and checking where a jump occurs `True -> False`, which corresponds to a difference of `-1` (boolean: `True`!). However, if a jump of `+1` (boolean: `True`)  occurs we don't care, because this means we go from `False -> True` so we can leave the element set to `True`. This leads to the following simple expression:

```py
mask = np.isin(primes + 2, primes)
mask[np.diff(mask, prepend=False)] = True
```

PS: you are including too much information that does not concern your question. You are more likely to get an answer if you keep it to the basics, in your case: "How to flip all `False` entries right after `True` entries?".

Comment: @slothrop as I mention in the answer, that does not matter. In case False->True, the mask is already True so it does not matter if we set it to True.

Comment: @slothrop Thanks for noticing! I have changed this, `bool(-1)` is `True` as well indeed.